In Mad Men, does the Dr Pepper Machine from 1960 prevent people from taking more bottles than they paid for?

In the TV show, Mad Men, season 3, Ep 6, there is scene at a hospital after a British accountant gets his foot chopped off by a lawn mower.
There is a Dr Pepper machine and once 10 cents is put in, we can open the narrow door with a handle and take out one bottle of drink.
From what I observed, once this narrow door is opened, there is nothing prevents a person from taking more than one bottle of drinks from their slots. I am wondering if there is actually an anti-theft mechanism in place or not.

You've never seen or used one of these machines, have you? I have. No, they don't work that way. I can't explain the mechanics of it, but you only get one selection.

Vending fridges that let you take as many as you like used to be popular. This isn't it.

A similar style of vending machine has been restored here;



As you can see, each bottle is actually kept behind a geared mechanism with just the neck pointing outwards. When you pull it out, you're 'using' the dime to unlock the gear and until a second coin is added, the gears are now locked in place and prevent an additional bottle being taken.

The one shown in the show is a Vendo 56 (or something very similar). The owner's manual has some nice info about the locking mechanism;

And specifically notes that if it vends more than one bottle it may be because the 'gates' are not locking correctly.


Interesting. I wonder how it stops you from pulling two bottles out simultaneously, though.

"The springs are calibrated to hold only one bottle securely in place, preventing two or more from being dispensed simultaneously. If more than one bottle is selected or pulled, the mechanism prevents the entire row from being dispensed at once, ensuring the integrity of the dispensing process."

@DarthPseudonym - I feel like this sort of dispenser would be very vulnerable to 'hacking' using a shim to prevent the mechanism from recognising that a bottle has been pulled

Wonder if this influenced the grooved or spotted textures on Coke and Pepsi bottles back then.

@Valorum also vulnerable to a brick. These sorts of mechanisms are to keep mostly honest people honest.

@Valorum It seems that way, doesn't it?  I assume that sort of thing is why modern vending machines generally rely on a chute that keeps the actual storage section a long way away from the customer.

@DarthPseudonym - People still work out how to scam them

Oh, I'm aware. But it's a lot more difficult to monkey with the mechanics if they're way up in there.

@DarthPseudonym: Some machines have one or more bars with a V-shaped notch and a slot for each product.  The gates have a spring-loaded-to-center projection which will attempt to push the bar or bars into a different position or combination of positions for each product, and a second more rigid projection that will fit in the slot if the bar is properly positioned.  The bar or bars can only be lined up to match one gate's projections at a time, and while a gate's projection is in the slot, the bars can't move to line up with any other gates.

@Valorum Why have you rejected my proposed edit? The review say “deviates from the original intent”, but that doesn’t make any sense to me; all I proposed was a transcription of the semi-legible images of text.

@ElementsInSpace - I've already described the contents of the manual and anyone wishing to read it can click the attached link

@ElementsInSpace - I have no objection to you adding the transcription to the meta text (for screen readers) but I do object to you dumping it into the body of the answer.

Low res images of text are awful.

We teenagers would take a cup and bottle opener to the machine.  You can open a bottle and let the contents drain into the cup.  Pretty frustrating for the next guy who has to buy an empty bottle to get at the full one.

@B.Goddard - You need a dime to open the fridge door, but then you've got access to five bottles.

@Valorum  Probably depends on the machine.  The one at the local CO-OP you could just open the door.   Huh, I haven't had strawberry pop in over half a century....
